# How can I insert a blinking cursor into a div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a basic text editor using angularjs (or just pure javascript). The idea is that I will have a div to contain the text, instead of using `textarea`. I want the user to be able to click anywhere inside the div and have a blinking cursor appear where they click. I really have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions? By the way, I would prefer not to use `contentEditable`.

Comment: Why not contenteditable?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen: It seems he wants to do it manually, as programming exercise.

Comment: @Mortiz seems right ... and the contentEditable piece seems required because the browser's edit capabilities are not completely separated from the OS's understanding that something is a field for data entry and modification ... hence the cursor being a blinking I/O signal... I/O is serious business. It can't be simulated or "treated" as I/O ... either it's I/O or it's not. That's why HTML is so particular about which items are editable. It transcends the browser and gets into OS/hardware input/output.

Comment: The OP **explicitly** stated he didn't want to use `contenteditable`. He wants to do it manually. For that reason, this is not a duplicate, and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 4):

Since you prefer not to use `contenteditable`, Here's a few suggestions you could have a look at to get a blinking cursor, manually:

- Overlay the div with a canvas element, get the click's position, and animate a line on the canvas at that position.
- Overlay a animated `.gif` containing the blinking line at the click's position.
- Use a animated `.gif` containing the blinking line as the div's background, and set the background-position, depending on the click's location.
- For the above two suggestions, instead of a `.gif`, you can use a static image, and toggle it.

You'll have to keep in mind that the line will have to snap to the closest character boundary, so you won't have your cursor blinking in the middle of a character. Using a monospaced font would make that a lot easier.

You will still have to write the other features a text field has, though:

- Text manipulation.
- Selections.
- Copy / pasting

Answer (score 2):

You can make the div editable by adding contentEditable="true" attribute to the div element.

```
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

As you mentioned you wanted to avoid using of contentEditable then you can go for Javascript/Jquery plugin. It will be very easy for you if you use plugin rather developing it on your own. Here is a jquery plugin which can come in handy. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 1):

you could try setting the div to `contenteditable`

```
<div contenteditable>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3N26/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are looking for html5 `contenteditable` attribute.

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable